# Getting only images from JSON response using AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, filenames

I have a REST call which gives the all attachments related to a Id which I pass to that call.

The JSON response should be like this

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"filename": "test.txt",
"size": 594,
"description": "comment",
"createdAt": "2014-04-07 12:53:24",
"binaryId": 1
},
{
"id": 2,
"filename": "dummy.png",
"size": 496,
"description": "comment",
"createdAt": "2014-04-07 12:53:34",
"binaryId": 2
},
{
"id": 3,
"filename": "else.pdf",
"size": 496,
"description": "comment",
"createdAt": "2014-04-07 12:53:34",
"binaryId": 3
},
{
"id": 4,
"filename": "some.jpg",
"size": 496,
"description": "comment",
"createdAt": "2014-04-07 12:53:34",
"binaryId": 4
}
]
```

Like this I will get all the files with all extensions.

So what I need here is to get only the images (.jpg, .png) from that json response ignoring other files like pdfs, text files etc.

How can I do this usimg AngularJS? Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.sampleImageArray = [];
    $scope.imageArray = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "filename": "test.txt",
            "size": 594,
            "description": "comment",
            "createdAt": "2014-04-07 12:53:24",
            "binaryId": 1
        },
 {
"id": 2,
"filename": "dummy.png",
"size": 496,
"description": "comment",
"createdAt": "2014-04-07 12:53:34",
"binaryId": 2
},
 {
"id": 3,
"filename": "else.pdf",
"size": 496,
"description": "comment",
"createdAt": "2014-04-07 12:53:34",
"binaryId": 3
},
{
"id": 4,
"filename": "some.jpg",
"size": 496,
"description": "comment",
"createdAt": "2014-04-07 12:53:34",
"binaryId": 4
 }
    ];

   angular.forEach($scope.imageArray, function (data) {
            var extension = data.filename.substr((data.filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1));
            if(extension=="png" || extension=="jpg" || extension=="jpeg")
                $scope.sampleImageArray.push(data);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use native [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
var images = response.filter(function(el) {
    return /\.(png|jpe?g)$/.test(el.filename);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

untested:

```
var files = [];
angular.forEach($data, $value)
{
    var filename = $value['filename'];
    var length = filename.length;
    var extension = filename.substr(length-3, 3);
    if(extension == "jpg") files.push($value);
}
```